# Nginx SSL certificate

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have recieved two files from the certification service : CSR.txt : Looks like this :

```
        -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
Code
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

and Private_Key.txt with same format
I'm trying to set them up on Nginx but I'm always getting this error when I restart Nginx

```
failed (SSL: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line error:140DC009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:PEM lib)
```

I have renamed CSR.txt to domain.crt and private_key.txt to domain_key.key
my nginx config :

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name domain.com;

    root html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/domain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /usr/share/nginx/www/domain.com/domain_key.key;

    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: Then what should I do ?

Comment: Moved mine to an answer. You need to ask your SSL provider for a certificate, or dig deeper into the files they gave you and find it if they already have.

Comment: Ok , I'll send them an email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per ceejayoz. In most cases the process works like:

You generate:

```
cert.key
cert.csr (using cert.key)
```

You send cert.csr to the certification service (CA).
The CA sends you:

```
cert.pem
```

`cert.pem` is your signed certificate and should look like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIICpjCCAY4CAQAwYTEaMBgGA1UEAxMRZG9jcy4zY2JldGEuY28udWsxDzANBgNV
...
efqf6gYqezWiXs1s5aNh363F1j+o7TWi0D5ayEBv/lihAmLs4dsaJzSvZiWVxnIr
5hUED99Ne1WUbg==
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

The key `cert.key` should look like:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpQIBAAKCAQEAqXpfLXr2oRPwP+Pt4Az+iHldiHrIDnVW/uWY3MPvAJN8BWLe
...
f2UKtbEUsSDQ2BWiQia/3VUzLOlDArYxqA7kZFKes2z9ji8vobPG27o=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The CSR `cert.csr` should look like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIIEqjCCApICAQAwZTEeMBwGA1UEAxMVZGV2Y2lyY3MuM2NiZXRhLmNvLnVrMQ8w
...
MctmU41Owfq+sIOGZ7G4zZqezUYownWt13hbprLk4DtWWEENRmvNinl0uCjAUA==
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

Some CA's will generate the key and CSR for you as a convenience (startssl can do this) but either way to operate your nginx site you need only the `cert.pem` and `key.pem` files. Can you get those from the certificate source?

When you get them you should be able to do:

```
openssl rsa -in key.pem -modulus

openssl rsa -in cert.pem -modulus
```

That will print out the cert and the key modulus. They must match.

You can dump a request with:

```
openssl req -in cert.csr
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: How do you send cert.csr to the certification service (CA)?

Comment: Aymane, usually you paste it's contents into the CA's web portal when you are requesting the certificate and parting with the money for the cert. The CSR can go anywhere, it's the .key file you must keep safe.

Answer (score 2):

A CSR is a **request** for a certificate, not a certificate. In most cases, it's something you'd generate, not someone else.

It is used by your SSL provider to create a certificate, which they'd provide you (as a .crt file, usually).

Incidentally, it's better for security if you generate the private key (as it's supposed to be *private*). Follow @davey's instructions to build one and the requisite CSR.